# GPS 5.0.2 - Build fails instantly with "Invalid Context, Cannot Build"

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

We have a fairly old Ada project where we are using GPS 5.0.2 (20110607) hosted on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu with GNAT Pro 6.4.2 (20110614-45).

GPS is able to perform the "check semantic" and "compile file" functions, but upon selection of "build main" or "build all," it fails immediately with the message `Invalid context, cannot build`.

A google search of this revealed that there was a bug that was fixed at one point dealing with this issue (it had to do with symlinks in the project tree), yet there are no symlinks and the workaround suggested does not work.

Build currently and has always worked perfectly when doing it from the command line, and build from GPS menu works fine on everyone's development computer except mine. We have checked environment variables, deleted the Gnat directory (and loaded one from a working computer), and deleted all Git repos and re-cloned from the server. At this point, I am out of ideas as to how to get it to work. It was my original understanding that everything GPS needs to know about a project is contained in the `.gpr` file.

Is there a settings location that I don't know about? Any ideas why this message pops up when I try to build, or what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes problems like this can be fixed by deleting the `~/.gps`directory, which contains your personal settings.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks, I never would have found this otherwise.